# free-jqGrid search button does not work on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

The search button works on the first click, but once it is closed either by clicking the X (close button) or by running a search (setting to close after search) it does not open, there are also no errors in the console so I am unable to determine what is wrong and how to fix it.

```
var previouslySelectedRow = null;
var rowIsSelected = null;
var previousRowIsSelected = null;
var currentRowId;
var currentCount;
var cancelEditing = function(theGrid) {
    var lrid;
    if (typeof previouslySelectedRow !== "undefined") {
        // cancel editing of the previous selected row if it was in editing state.
        // jqGrid hold intern savedRow array inside of jqGrid object,
        // so it is safe to call restoreRow method with any id parameter
        // if jqGrid not in editing state
        theGrid.jqGrid('restoreRow', previouslySelectedRow);

        // now we need to restore the icons in the formatter:"actions"
        lrid = $.jgrid.jqID(previouslySelectedRow);
        $("tr#" + lrid + " div.ui-inline-edit").show();
        $("tr#" + lrid + " div.ui-inline-save, " + "tr#" + lrid + " div.ui-inline-cancel").hide();
    }
};

var parsedResult = JSON.parse(DecodeAscii(result));
ShowDebugNotification("DEBUG INFO(" + ajaxCall + "): <br />" + result, false);
$("#productsTable").jqGrid({
        data: parsedResult,
        datatype: "local",
        loadonce: true,
        height: 'auto',
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        colNames: [
            'Product Id', 'Add', 'Product Name', 'Product Code', 'Customer Price'
        ],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Id', width: 0, hidden:true },
            { name: "actions", template: "actions", width: 50, formatoptions:{
                delbutton: false,
                editbutton: false
            } },
            { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 550, search: true, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']} },
            { name: 'ProductCode', index: 'ProductCode', width: 150, search: true, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']} },
            { name: 'Price', index: 'Price', width: 100, search: false, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions:{decimalSeparator:".", thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 2, prefix: "$"}}
        ],
        rowNum: 15,
        rowList: [5, 10, 15, 20],
        pager: true,
        gridView: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        iconSet: "jQueryUI",
        sortname: 'Name',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        inlineEditing: { keys: false },
        actionsNavOptions: {
            addToCarticon: "ui-icon-cart",
            addToCarttitle: "Add item to the cart",
            custom: [
                { action: "addToCart", position: "first", onClick: function (options) { 
                    var rowData = $('#productsTable').getRowData(options.rowid);
                    var cartButton = $(".ui-icon", "#jAddToCartButton_"+options.rowid);
                    if(cartButton.hasClass("ui-icon-cancel")){
                        cart.shift(rowData);
                        cartButton.removeClass("ui-icon-cancel");
                        cartButton.addClass("ui-icon-cart");
                    }
                    else if(cartButton.hasClass("ui-icon-cart")){
                        cart.push(rowData);
                        cartButton.removeClass("ui-icon-cart");
                        cartButton.addClass("ui-icon-cancel");
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        loadComplete: function() {
            $("#add-product-dialog-loading-message").hide();
            $(".spinner").hide();
            $("#add-product-dialog-form").dialog("open");

            //for each object in cart
            //if prodcut ID matches product Id in product 
            //grid then set button to a cancel icon
            if(cart.length !== 0){
                var cartIds = [];
                var jsonCart = JSON.stringify(cart);
                var parsedJsonCart = JSON.parse(jsonCart);
                var productsInCart = $.grep(parsedJsonCart, function(el, i){
                    cartIds.push(el.Id);
                });

                var currentRows = $('#productsTable').getRowData();
                var shownProductsThatAreInCart = $.grep(currentRows, function (el, i) {
                    return $.inArray(el.Id, cartIds) !== -1;
                });

                if(shownProductsThatAreInCart.length > 0){
                    var rowIds = $(this).jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                    $.each(rowIds, function(k, v) {
                        rowData = $('#productsTable').getRowData(v);

                        if($.inArray(rowData['Id'], cartIds) !== -1){
                            alert("Matched Product:\nRowData['id'] = " + rowData['Id'] + "\nto\nProduct in cart: " + cartIds.Id);
                            $(".ui-icon", "#jAddToCartButton_"+v).removeClass("ui-icon-cart");
                            $(".ui-icon", "#jAddToCartButton_"+v).addClass("ui-icon-cancel");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        gridComplete: function() {
        }
    });
    $("#productsTable").jqGrid("navGrid", {edit:false,add:false,del:false},
    {},// use default settings for edit
    {},// use default settings for add
    {},// delete instead that del:false we need this
    {multipleSearch:false,overlay:false,ignoreCase:true,closeAfterSearch:true,closeOnEscape:true,showQuery:true});
```

I don't think its a bug as I have seen many demos demonstrating how it is supposed to work, I am guessing I have a mis-configuration, please have a look over my code and help determine the issue.

One thing to keep in mind is I am getting the data to load the grid via an ajax call that returns json, all manipulation is done on the client, there is no posting data back to server at all.

Thank you!

Comment: Another data point - I can click the button to bring the search dialog up and close it immediately then try to open it again and it will not open

Comment: Which version of free jqGrid you use? Could you prepare the demo (in JSFiddle for example), which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I am using the latest 4.10.0 - I will put something together.

Comment: You can get some old demo like http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/qzxwfquq/ and modify it.

Comment: I built it from scratch, took a while but I duplicated behaviour, the code is messy sorry.. https://jsfiddle.net/su7mf5k9/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is the combination of Searching options which you use:

```
{
    multipleSearch: false, // it's default and can be removed
    overlay: false, // !!! the option make the problem
    ignoreCase: true, // it's not exist at all
    closeAfterSearch: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    showQuery: true
}
```

The usage of the option `overlay: false` is bad because it makes another option `toTop: true` not working and the Searching dialog will be placed as the children of jQuery UI Dialog. If you remove the option then one can work with the Searching Dialog more easy and the second problem (a bug in calculation of position of jqGrid Searching Dialog) will not exist. Look at the modified demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/su7mf5k9/3/

**UPDATED:** It seems one have the problem in creating **modal** jqGrid dialog inside of **modal** jQuery UI dialog. The problem could be solved by removing `modal: true` option from the outer jQuery UI dialog. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/su7mf5k9/3/

In general one could create hybrid solution which changes the type of jQuery UI dialog from modal to non-modal dynamically, but it could be tricky https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/su7mf5k9/5/

Comment: I took a look at your fiddle, and there is no longer an issue with the search not opening but the field to type your search term no longer works, I had to set overlay to false so that way the search field was no longer disabled. If you go to your fiddle and just add overlay: false back in you will see that will re-enable the field. - Thanks again for your time!

Comment: @Noctane: I see the problem now. Thank you! I will fix the bug and will inform you after the new code will be on GitHub.

Comment: @Noctane: I posted [the first fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/29c49554504ca4b3c39ef905c02f3f49d65b042e), which makes your original code working. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/su7mf5k9/4/ where I use the URL from GitHub. I recommend you to include `localReader: { id: "Id"}` if you use `datatype: "local"` and `jsonReader: { id: "Id" }`. You can remove hidden `"Id"` column. jqGrid will assign `id` attribute from `Id` property of input data. It will be helpful for editing too. I will inform you when I post the second bug fix (`overlay: false` removed). It's more difficult.

Comment: @Noctane: I analysed the problem and wrote my results in **UPDATED** part of my answer. I don't found other simple way to fix the problem using **both** modals

Comment: I am working with your first fix and it is working well, if you don't see issues in doing it that way I may just go with it. If you do see issues with it then in your opinion do you think option 2 would be the safer bet?

Comment: @Noctane: I think that *you* should decide which way is better for your *environment*. There are no best choice, which is the best in all cases. I think it good that you have two working alternative ways and you can choose between there.

Comment: Okay, thanks again for your help I truly appreciate it!